# How do you protect /handle authenticated routes with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, permissions, angular-ui-router, authorization

Just started using angular and I'm trying to learn as fast as I can. I'm relatively new to SPA's so please bear with me and feel free to tell me if what I want to do is not feasible. What I'm currently stuck on now, is how do I protect my routes when using the ui-router?

**What do I want to do?**

There are routes that I don't want non-logged in users to access.
For example, **/home** and **/login** are okay for ***anonymous*** users.
**/dashboard** should only be for those that are ***logged in.***

I want it so if a user tries to access /dashboard in the future without being logged in, they are not able to.

**What have I already tried?**

I have tried using the angular-permission module found here: https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission
The problem is..I'm not quite sure how to use it (nor if I'm using it properly).

**What is currently happening?**

In my login controller, once a user submits their username and password it makes a /POST to my web-sever. Once it gets the result, (regardless of what it is for the moment) I've got it redirecting to /dashboard.

Right now nothing should be getting to the /dashboard because no permissions have been set, yet I am (incorrectly) allowed to see the dashboard. I can both (1) successfully be redirected to the dashboard without permission and (2) access /dashboard without permission.

**What does my code look like right now?**

*controllers.js*

```
var controllers = angular.module('controllers',[])
// Login Controller -- This handles the login page that the user can enter
// enter his username & password.
controllers.controller('loginController', function($scope, $state,$location, LoginService){
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.password = ""

    $scope.login = function(){
        var data = ({email:"test", password: "ayylmao"})
        LoginService.login(data).then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log("ERROR!");
            console.log(err);
            $state.go('dashboard')
        })
    }
})
```

*app.js*

```
//Definition: The parent module
var myApp = angular.module('clipboardApp', ['services','controllers', 'permission','ui.router']);

//Code below taken from the angular-permission docs.
angular
  .module('fooModule', ['permission', 'user'])
  .run(function (PermissionStore, User) {
    // Define anonymous permission)
    PermissionStore
      .definePermission('anonymous', function (stateParams) {
      // If the returned value is *truthy* then the user has the permission, otherwise they don't.
        //True indicates anonymous.
        //Always returning true to indicate that it's anonymous
        return true;
      });
  });



//This will be serving as the router.
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    //By default go
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    //Views are
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller:  'loginController'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController',
            data: {
              permissions: {
                except: ['anonymous'],
                redirectTo: 'login'
              }
            }
          });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example with secured routes. In this example any state start with app. will go via the auth interceptor. $transitions.onBefore hook can be use as follows to satisfy your requirement.

```
.run(($transitions, $state, $injector) => {
    $transitions.onBefore({
      to: 'app.**'
    }, () => {
      const $window = $injector.get('$window');
      if (!$window.sessionStorage.getItem('user')) {
        return $state.target('login', $state.transition.params());
      }
      return true
    });
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCN2hB34mMEmBJulyaAJ?p=info